# Translating Rails Timezones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

We internationalized our site months ago, but forgot one part: The drop down where a user picks their timezone.

How do you translate the following line:

```
  = f.time_zone_select :timezone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to translate? The names of the time zones?

Comment: Yup the names of the cities are different in different languages.

Comment: It's a great question: are the ActiveSupport::TimeZones only in English?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've come across the same problem. However, when I was trying to implement [Peter's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396623/translating-rails-timezones/1515729#1515729), a simpler solution occurred to me. The `time_zone_select` helper takes a `:model` option, which defaults to `ActiveSupport::TimeZone`. According to the API documentation, all this model has to do is return an array of timezone objects in the `all` method. We can then override the `to_s` method to return the translation (defaulting to the original if the translation isn't found). Here is the class:

```
# lib/i18n_time_zone.rb
class I18nTimeZone < ActiveSupport::TimeZone
  def self.all
    super.map { |z| create(z.name, z.utc_offset) }
  end

  def to_s
    translated_name = I18n.t(name, :scope => :timezones, :default => name)
    "(GMT#{formatted_offset}) #{translated_name}"
  end
end
```

And in the view:

```
<%= time_zone_select :user, :time_zone, nil, :model => I18nTimeZone %>
```

With the translations specified in the translation file as before:

```
# es.yml
es:
  timezones:
    "International Date Line West":    "Línea de fecha internacional del oeste"
    "Pacific Time (US & Canada)":      "Tiempo pacífico (& de los E.E.U.U.; Canadá)"
    # and so on
```

Comment: Even simpler, you don't need to override self.all, that's already provided by ActiveSupport::TimeZone. So only +to_s+ is needed.

Comment: did a google translate dump for zh-CN if anyone needs a starting point https://gist.github.com/985302

Comment: when try to use your variant have error

`NoMethodError (undefined method [] for nil:NilClass)`

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't used Rails for several years @NazarHlynskyi, (this is a 9 year-old post!) - hopefully someone else will be able to help!

Answer (score 6):

I took some ideas in this post and built a gem to handle timezone translations. I've only got en and es translations right now but its pretty easy to add it to your app and add more locale. Just add this to your Gemfile:

gem i18n-timezones

You can grab the source here:

https://github.com/onomojo/i18n-timezones

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and fishwebby's answer made the trick easily. I needed the time zones translated to spanish so here I leave the list:

```
    "International Date Line West": "Línea de fecha internacional del oeste"
    "Midway Island": "Isla de Midway"
    "Samoa": "Samoa"
    "Hawaii": "Hawai"
    "Alaska": "Alaska"
    "Pacific Time (US & Canada)": "Hora del Pacífico (EE.UU. y Canadá)"
    "Tijuana": "Tijuana"
    "Mountain Time (US & Canada)": "Hora de las Montañas (EE.UU. y Canadá)"
    "Arizona": "Arizona"
    "Chihuahua": "Chihuahua"
    "Mazatlan": "Mazatlán"
    "Central Time (US & Canada)": "Hora central (EE.UU. y Canadá)"
    "Saskatchewan": "Saskatchewan"
    "Guadalajara": "Guadalajara"
    "Mexico City": "Ciudad de México"
    "Monterrey": "Monterrey"
    "Central America": "América Central"
    "Eastern Time (US & Canada)": "Hora del Este (EE.UU. y Canadá)"
    "Indiana (East)": "Indiana (Este)"
    "Bogota": "Bogotá"
    "Lima": "Lima"
    "Quito": "Quito"
    "Atlantic Time (Canada)": "Hora del Atlántico (Canadá)"
    "Caracas": "Caracas"
    "La Paz": "La Paz"
    "Santiago": "Santiago"
    "Newfoundland": "Terranova"
    "Brasilia": "Brasilia"
    "Buenos Aires": "Buenos Aires"
    "Georgetown": "Georgetown"
    "Greenland": "Groenlandia"
    "Mid-Atlantic": "Atlántico medio"
    "Azores": "Azores"
    "Cape Verde Is.": "Isla Cabo Verde"
    "Dublin": "Dublín"
    "Edinburgh": "Edimburgo"
    "Lisbon": "Lisboa"
    "London": "Londres"
    "Casablanca": "Casablanca"
    "Monrovia": "Monrovia"
    "UTC": "UTC"
    "Belgrade": "Belgrado"
    "Bratislava": "Bratislava"
    "Budapest": "Budapest"
    "Ljubljana": "Ljubljana"
    "Prague": "Praga"
    "Sarajevo": "Sarajevo"
    "Skopje": "Skopje"
    "Warsaw": "Varsovia"
    "Zagreb": "Zagreb"
    "Brussels": "Bruselas"
    "Copenhagen": "Copenhague"
    "Madrid": "Madrid"
    "Paris": "París"
    "Amsterdam": "Amsterdam"
    "Berlin": "Berlín"
    "Bern": "Berna"
    "Rome": "Roma"
    "Stockholm": "Estocolmo"
    "Vienna": "Viena"
    "West Central Africa": "Centro-Oeste de África"
    "Bucharest": "Bucarest"
    "Cairo": "El Cairo"
    "Helsinki": "Helsinki"
    "Kyev": "Kyev"
    "Riga": "Riga"
    "Sofia": "Sofía"
    "Tallinn": "Tallin"
    "Vilnius": "Vilnius"
    "Athens": "Atenas"
    "Istanbul": "Estambul"
    "Minsk": "Minsk"
    "Jerusalem": "Jerusalén"
    "Harare": "Harare"
    "Pretoria": "Pretoria"
    "Moscow": "Moscú"
    "St. Petersburg": "San Petersburgo"
    "Volgograd": "Volgogrado"
    "Kuwait": "Kuwait"
    "Riyadh": "Riad"
    "Nairobi": "Nairobi"
    "Baghdad": "Bagdad"
    "Tehran": "Teherán"
    "Abu Dhabi": "Abu Dhabi"
    "Muscat": "Moscatel"
    "Baku": "Bakú"
    "Tbilisi": "Tbilisi"
    "Yerevan": "Ereván"
    "Kabul": "Kabul"
    "Ekaterinburg": "Ekaterinburg"
    "Islamabad": "Islamabad"
    "Karachi": "Karachi"
    "Tashkent": "Tashkent"
    "Chennai": "Chennai"
    "Kolkata": "Kolkata"
    "Mumbai": "Mumbai"
    "New Delhi": "Nueva Delhi"
    "Kathmandu": "Katmandú"
    "Astana": "Astana"
    "Dhaka": "Dhaka"
    "Sri Jayawardenepura": "Sri Jayawardenepura"
    "Almaty": "Almaty"
    "Novosibirsk": "Novosibirsk"
    "Rangoon": "Rangún"
    "Bangkok": "Bangkok"
    "Hanoi": "Hanoi"
    "Jakarta": "Yakarta"
    "Krasnoyarsk": "Krasnoyarsk"
    "Beijing": "Beijing"
    "Chongqing": "Chongqing"
    "Hong Kong": "Hong Kong"
    "Urumqi": "Urumqi"
    "Kuala Lumpur": "Kuala Lumpur"
    "Singapore": "Singapur"
    "Taipei": "Taipei"
    "Perth": "Perth"
    "Irkutsk": "Irkutsk"
    "Ulaan Bataar": "Ulán Bator"
    "Seoul": "Seúl"
    "Osaka": "Osaka"
    "Sapporo": "Sapporo"
    "Tokyo": "Tokio"
    "Yakutsk": "Yakutsk"
    "Darwin": "Darwin"
    "Adelaide": "Adelaida"
    "Canberra": "Canberra"
    "Melbourne": "Melbourne"
    "Sydney": "Sydney"
    "Brisbane": "Brisbane"
    "Hobart": "Hobart"
    "Vladivostok": "Vladivostok"
    "Guam": "Guam"
    "Port Moresby": "Port Moresby"
    "Magadan": "Magadan"
    "Solomon Is.": "Islas Salomón"
    "New Caledonia": "Nueva Caledonia"
    "Fiji": "Fiji"
    "Kamchatka": "Kamchatka"
    "Marshall Is.": "Islas Marshall"
    "Auckland": "Auckland"
    "Wellington": "Wellington"
    "Nuku'alofa": "Nuku'alofa"
```

Comment: Oh and to output the country from the model whan already saved:

<%=t @user.zona_horaria, :scope => "timezones" %>

Comment: That's very helpful. I don't suppose anybody has a German, French and Portuguese list lying around? This site has some of the zones translated into all those languages but they use a different list: http://unicode.org/repos/cldr-tmp/trunk/diff/summary/root.html

Answer (score 4):

[fishwebby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396623/translating-rails-timezones/1531053#1531053)'s solution didn't work for me when priority time zones where provided in the time_zone_select. Easiest is to just stick this in /config/initializers/time_zone_patch.rb :

```
  # See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396623/translating-rails-timezones
  class ActiveSupport::TimeZone
    def to_s
      offset = "(GMT#{formatted_offset})"
      translated_name = I18n.t(name, :scope => :time_zones, :default => name)
      %(#{offset} #{translated_name})
    end
  end
```

No need to modify your view code either.

You can use it in conjunction with [this fork of the rails-i18n gem](https://github.com/onomojo/rails-i18n). It includes the spanish timezone translations that were provided in another response to this question. I will be adding more translations as needed or as provided until the original gem authors merge the timezones into their project.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that this would need to be done manually in the same way that any other I18n translations are done in Rails. This would mean setting up locale files with the translations. Something like:

```
# es.yml
es:
  timezones:
    "International Date Line West":    "Línea de fecha internacional del oeste"
    "Pacific Time (US & Canada)":      "Tiempo pacífico (& de los E.E.U.U.; Canadá)"
    # and so on
```

You could overwrite the `time_zone_options_for_select` method (which is used by `time_zone_select`) with the following:

```
def time_zone_options_for_select(selected = nil, priority_zones = nil, model = ::ActiveSupport::TimeZone)
  zone_options = ""

  zones = model.all
  convert_zones = lambda do |list|
    list.map do |z|
      localized_name = I18n.t(z.name, :scope => :timezones, :default => z.name)
      [ "(GMT#{z.formatted_offset}) #{localized_name}", z.name ]
    end
  end

  if priority_zones
    if priority_zones.is_a?(Regexp)
      priority_zones = model.all.find_all {|z| z =~ priority_zones}
    end
    zone_options += options_for_select(convert_zones[priority_zones], selected)
    zone_options += "<option value=\"\" disabled=\"disabled\">-------------</option>\n"

    zones = zones.reject { |z| priority_zones.include?( z ) }
  end

  zone_options += options_for_select(convert_zones[zones], selected)
  zone_options
end
```

The changes are:

```
convert_zones = lambda do |list|
  list.map do |z|
    localized_name = I18n.t(z.name, :scope => :timezones, :default => z.name)
    [ "(GMT#{z.formatted_offset}) #{localized_name}", z.name ]
  end
end
```

What we're doing is, getting the localized name from the TimeZone name with I18n.t which is looking in `config/locales/LANG.yml` formatted as shown above. If we can't find the translation, we just fallback on using the TimeZone name.

Now that we've done this setup, we should be able to use :

```
f.time_zone_select :timezone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all
```

or the shorter

```
f.time_zone_select :timezone # defaults to ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all
```

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble translating the time zones with .'s in them, like "St. Petersburg"

`"translation missing: en, time_zones, St,  Petersburg"`

I removed the .'s from the keys, and changed this:

`translated_name = I18n.t(name, :scope => :time_zones, :default => name)`

to:

`translated_name = I18n.t(name.gsub(".", ""), :scope => :time_zones, :default => name)`

There are four keys with .'s:

- Cape Verde Is.
- St. Petersburg
- Solomon Is.
- Marshall Is.

Comment: The period is a scope separator in I18n. You need to change the scope separator to something else when making the I18n lookup, e.g.: `I18n.t(name, :scope => :timezones, :default => name, :separator => "\001")`

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer from @DaveHollingworth worked for us under Rails 3.2, but we hit the error reported by @NazarHlynskyi when we upgraded to Rails 4.2:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method [] for nil:NilClass)
```

To work around this I have resorted to monkey patching the `ActiveSupport::TimeZone`, with the `#to_s` method above.

So now in `config/initializers/time_zone.rb` we have the following

```
class ActiveSupport::TimeZone
  def to_s
    translated_name = I18n.t(name, :scope => :timezones, :default => name)
    "(GMT#{formatted_offset}) #{translated_name}"
  end
end
```

and we no longer have the separate `I18nTimeZone` model.

Monkey-patching may not be to your liking, in which case you will probably need to get a bit more intimate with the internal changes to `ActiveSupport::TimeZone` in order to recreate the behaviour, but the monkey-patching option provided a quick resolution for us.

Answer (score 0):

French translations:

```
"American Samoa": "Samoa américaines" # -11:00
#"International Date Line West": "" # -11:00
"Midway Island": "Îles Midway" # -11:00
"Hawaii": "Hawaï" # -10:00
"Alaska": "Alaska" # -09:00
"Pacific Time (US & Canada)": "Pacific Time (É.-U. et Canada)" # -08:00
"Tijuana": "Tijuana" # -08:00
"Arizona": "Arizona" # -07:00
"Chihuahua": "Chihuahua" # -07:00
"Mazatlan": "Mazatlán" # -07:00
"Mountain Time (US & Canada)": "Mountain Time (É.-U. et Canada)" # -07:00
"Central America": "Amérique centrale" # -06:00
"Central Time (US & Canada)": "Central Time (É.-U. et Canada)" # -06:00
"Guadalajara": "Guadalajara" # -06:00
"Mexico City": "Mexico" # -06:00
"Monterrey": "Monterrey" # -06:00
"Saskatchewan": "Saskatchewan" # -06:00
"Bogota": "Bogotá" # -05:00
"Eastern Time (US & Canada)": "Heure de l'Est (É.-U. et Canada)" # -05:00
"Indiana (East)": "Indiana (est)" # -05:00
"Lima": "Lima" # -05:00
"Quito": "Quito" # -05:00
"Caracas": "Caracas" # -04:30
"Atlantic Time (Canada)": "Atlantic Time (Canada)" # -04:00
"Georgetown": "Georgetown" # -04:00
"La Paz": "La Paz" # -04:00
"Santiago": "Santiago" # -04:00
"Newfoundland": "Terre-Neuve" # -03:30
"Brasilia": "Brasilia" # -03:00
"Buenos Aires": "Buenos Aires" # -03:00
"Greenland": "Groenland" # -03:00
#"Mid-Atlantic": "" # -02:00
"Azores": "Açores" # -01:00
"Cape Verde Is.": "Cap-Vert" # -01:00
"Casablanca": "Casablanca" # +00:00
"Dublin": "Dublin" # +00:00
"Edinburgh": "Édimbourg" # +00:00
"Lisbon": "Lisbonne" # +00:00
"London": "Londres" # +00:00
"Monrovia": "Monrovia" # +00:00
"UTC": "UTC" # +00:00
"Amsterdam": "Amsterdam" # +01:00
"Belgrade": "Belgrade" # +01:00
"Berlin": "Berlin" # +01:00
"Bern": "Berne" # +01:00
"Bratislava": "Bratislava" # +01:00
"Brussels": "Bruxelles" # +01:00
"Budapest": "Budapest" # +01:00
"Copenhagen": "Copenhague" # +01:00
"Ljubljana": "Ljubljana" # +01:00
"Madrid": "Madrid" # +01:00
"Paris": "Paris" # +01:00
"Prague": "Prague" # +01:00
"Rome": "Rome" # +01:00
"Sarajevo": "Sarajevo" # +01:00
"Skopje": "Skopje" # +01:00
"Stockholm": "Stockholm" # +01:00
"Vienna": "Vienne" # +01:00
"Warsaw": "Varsovie" # +01:00
"West Central Africa": "Heure d'Afrique occidentale" # +01:00
"Zagreb": "Zagreb" # +01:00
"Athens": "Athènes" # +02:00
"Bucharest": "Bucarest" # +02:00
"Cairo": "Caire" # +02:00
"Harare": "Harare" # +02:00
"Helsinki": "Helsinki" # +02:00
"Istanbul": "Istanbul" # +02:00
"Jerusalem": "Jérusalem" # +02:00
"Kyiv": "Kiev" # +02:00
"Pretoria": "Pretoria" # +02:00
"Riga": "Riga" # +02:00
"Sofia": "Sofia" # +02:00
"Tallinn": "Tallinn" # +02:00
"Vilnius": "Vilnius" # +02:00
"Baghdad": "Bagdad" # +03:00
"Kuwait": "Koweït" # +03:00
"Minsk": "Minsk" # +03:00
"Nairobi": "Nairobi" # +03:00
"Riyadh": "Riyad" # +03:00
"Tehran": "Téhéran" # +03:30
"Abu Dhabi": "Abou Dabi" # +04:00
"Baku": "Bakou" # +04:00
"Moscow": "Moscou" # +04:00
"Muscat": "Mascate" # +04:00
"St. Petersburg": "Saint-Pétersbourg" # +04:00
"Tbilisi": "Tbilissi" # +04:00
"Volgograd": "Volgograd" # +04:00
"Yerevan": "Erevan" # +04:00
"Kabul": "Kaboul" # +04:30
"Islamabad": "Islamabad" # +05:00
"Karachi": "Karachi" # +05:00
"Tashkent": "Tachkent" # +05:00
"Chennai": "Chennai" # +05:30
"Kolkata": "Calcutta" # +05:30
"Mumbai": "Bombay" # +05:30
"New Delhi": "New Delhi" # +05:30
"Sri Jayawardenepura": "Sri Jayawardenapura" # +05:30
"Kathmandu": "Katmandou" # +05:45
"Almaty": "Almaty" # +06:00
"Astana": "Astana" # +06:00
"Dhaka": "Dacca" # +06:00
"Ekaterinburg": "Iekaterinbourg" # +06:00
"Rangoon": "Rangoun" # +06:30
"Bangkok": "Bangkok" # +07:00
"Hanoi": "Hanoï" # +07:00
"Jakarta": "Jakarta" # +07:00
"Novosibirsk": "Novossibirsk" # +07:00
"Beijing": "Pékin" # +08:00
"Chongqing": "Chongqing" # +08:00
"Hong Kong": "Hong Kong" # +08:00
"Krasnoyarsk": "Krasnoïarsk" # +08:00
"Kuala Lumpur": "Kuala Lumpur" # +08:00
"Perth": "Perth" # +08:00
"Singapore": "Singapour" # +08:00
"Taipei": "Taipei" # +08:00
"Ulaan Bataar": "Oulan-Bator" # +08:00
"Urumqi": "Ürümqi" # +08:00
"Irkutsk": "Irkoutsk" # +09:00
"Osaka": "Osaka" # +09:00
"Sapporo": "Sapporo" # +09:00
"Seoul": "Séoul" # +09:00
"Tokyo": "Tokyo" # +09:00
"Adelaide": "Adélaïde" # +09:30
"Darwin": "Darwin" # +09:30
"Brisbane": "Brisbane" # +10:00
"Canberra": "Canberra" # +10:00
"Guam": "Guam" # +10:00
"Hobart": "Hobart" # +10:00
"Melbourne": "Melbourne" # +10:00
"Port Moresby": "Port Moresby" # +10:00
"Sydney": "Sydney" # +10:00
"Yakutsk": "Iakoutsk" # +10:00
"New Caledonia": "Nouvelle-Calédonie" # +11:00
"Vladivostok": "Vladivostok" # +11:00
"Auckland": "Auckland" # +12:00
"Fiji": "Fidji" # +12:00
"Kamchatka": "Kamtchatka" # +12:00
"Magadan": "Magadan" # +12:00
"Marshall Is.": "Îles_Marshall" # +12:00
"Solomon Is.": "Îles Salomon" # +12:00
"Wellington": "Wellington" # +12:00
"Nuku'alofa": "Nuku'alofa" # +13:00
"Samoa": "Samoa" # +13:00
"Tokelau Is.": "Tokelau" # +14:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Japanese translations

```
ja:
  timezones:
    "International Date Line West": "国際日付変更線"
    "Midway Island": "ミッドウェイ諸島"
    "American Samoa": "米領サモア"
    "Samoa": "サモア"
    "Hawaii": "ハワイ"
    "Alaska": "アラスカ"
    "Pacific Time (US ＆ Canada)": "太平洋標準時 (アメリカ・カナダ)"
    "Tijuana": "ティファナ"
    "Mountain Time (US ＆ Canada)": "山岳部標準時 (アメリカ・カナダ)"
    "Arizona": "アリゾナ"
    "Chihuahua": "チワワ"
    "Mazatlan": "マサトラン"
    "Central Time (US ＆ Canada ": "中部標準時 (アメリカ・カナダ)"
    "Saskatchewan": "サスカチュワン"
    "Guadalajara": "グアダラハラ"
    "Mexico City": "メキシコシティ"
    "Monterrey": "モントレー"
    "Central America": "中央アメリカ"
    "Eastern Time (US ＆ Canada)": "東部標準時 (アメリカ・カナダ)"
    "Indiana (East)": "インディアナ (東)"
    "Bogota": "ボゴタ"
    "Lima": "リマ"
    "Quito": "キト"
    "Atlantic Time (Canada)": "大西洋標準時 (カナダ)"
    "Caracas": "カラカス"
    "La Paz": "ラパス"
    "Santiago": "サンティアゴ"
    "Newfoundland": "ニューファンドランド"
    "Brasilia": "ブラジリア"
    "Buenos Aires": "ブエノスアイレス"
    "Georgetown": "ジョージタウン"
    "Greenland": "グリーンランド"
    "Mid - Atlantic": "中部大西洋"
    "Azores": "アゾレス諸島"
    "Cape Verde Is": "カーボベルデ"
    "Dublin": "ダブリン"
    "Edinburgh": "エディンバラ"
    "Lisbon": "リスボン"
    "London": "ロンドン"
    "Casablanca": "カサブランカ"
    "Monrovia": "モンロビア"
    "UTC": "協定世界時"
    "Belgrade": "ベオグラード"
    "Bratislava": "ブラチスラヴァ"
    "Budapest": "ブダペスト"
    "Ljubljana": "リュブリャナ"
    "Prague": "プラハ"
    "Sarajevo": "サラエボ"
    "Skopje": "スコピエ"
    "Warsaw": "ワルシャワ"
    "Zagreb": "ザグレブ"
    "Brussels": "ブリュッセル"
    "Copenhagen": "コペンハーゲン"
    "Madrid": "マドリード"
    "Paris": "パリ"
    "Amsterdam": "アムステルダム"
    "Berlin": "ベルリン"
    "Bern": "ベルン"
    "Rome": "ローマ"
    "Stockholm": "ストックホルム"
    "Vienna": "ウィーン"
    "West Central Africa": "西中部アフリカ"
    "Bucharest": "ブカレスト"
    "Cairo": "カイロ"
    "Helsinki": "ヘルシンキ"
    "Kyiv": "キエフ"
    "Riga": "リガ"
    "Sofia": "ソフィア"
    "Tallinn": "タリン"
    "Vilnius": "ヴィリニュス"
    "Athens": "アテネ"
    "Istanbul": "イスタンブル"
    "Minsk": "ミンスク"
    "Jerusalem": "エルサレム"
    "Harare": "ハラレ"
    "Pretoria": "プレトリア"
    "Moscow": "モスクワ"
    "St. Petersburg": "サンクトペテルブルク"
    "Volgograd": "ボルゴグラード"
    "Kuwait": "クウェート"
    "Riyadh": "リヤド"
    "Nairobi": "ナイロビ"
    "Baghdad": "バグダード"
    "Tehran": "テヘラン"
    "Abu Dhabi": "アブダビ"
    "Muscat": "マスカット"
    "Baku": "バクー"
    "Tbilisi": "トビリシ"
    "Yerevan": "エレバン"
    "Kabul": "カーブル"
    "Ekaterinburg": "エカテリンブルク"
    "Islamabad": "イスラマバード"
    "Karachi": "カラチ"
    "Tashkent": "タシュケント"
    "Chennai": "チェンナイ"
    "Kolkata": "コルカタ"
    "Mumbai": "ムンバイ"
    "New Delhi": "ニューデリー"
    "Kathmandu": "カトマンズ"
    "Astana": "アスタナ"
    "Dhaka": "ダッカ"
    "Sri Jayawardenapura": "スリジャヤワルダナプラ"
    "Almaty": "アルマトイ"
    "Novosibirsk": "ノヴォシビルスク"
    "Rangoon": "ヤンゴン"
    "Bangkok": "バンコク"
    "Hanoi": "ハノイ"
    "Jakarta": "ジャカルタ"
    "Krasnoyarsk": "クラスノヤルスク"
    "Beijing": "北京市"
    "Chongqing": "重慶市"
    "Hong Kong": "香港"
    "Urumqi": "ウルムチ市"
    "Kuala Lumpur": "クアラルンプール"
    "Singapore": "シンガポール"
    "Taipei": "台北市"
    "Perth": "パース"
    "Irkutsk": "イルクーツク"
    "Ulaan Bataar": "ウランバートル"
    "Seoul": "ソウル"
    "Osaka": "大阪"
    "Sapporo": "札幌"
    "Tokyo": "東京"
    "Yakutsk": "ヤクーツク"
    "Darwin": "ダーウィン"
    "Adelaide": "アデレード"
    "Canberra": "キャンベラ"
    "Melbourne": "メルボルン"
    "Sydney": "シドニー"
    "Brisbane": "ブリスベン"
    "Hobart": "ホバート"
    "Vladivostok": "ウラジオストク"
    "Guam": "グアム"
    "Port Moresby": "ポートモレスビー"
    "Magadan": "マガダン"
    "Solomon Is": "ソロモン諸島"
    "New Caledonia": "ニューカレドニア"
    "Fiji": "フィジー"
    "Kamchatka": "カムチャツカ半島"
    "Marshall Is": "マーシャル諸島"
    "Auckland": "オークランド"
    "Wellington": "ウェリントン"
    "Nuku'alofa": "ヌクアロファ"
    "Tokelau Is": "トケラウ"
```